# I18n and ordinalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, locale, rails-i18n

To use the method [ordinalize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/ordinalize) for an english-speaking application I simply do this:

```
Time.now.day.ordinalize
```

But is there any pattern to apply this for other locales?

Comment: I created a PR on rails to support this feature. You can have a look on it. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method that you can use as it is hard coded in the `ordinal` method of rails. So, you have to create your own method.